# Segmentation Fault 11 in C++ processing text file

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, text-processing

I am trying to write a program in C++ in Mac to process a text file (table.txt) that has the following data:

> Tom 50 60 70.5
>   Jerry 80.3 65 91
>   Mark 75.2 77 92.7
>   Lucy 100 87.6 93

However, what I get from running it on terminal is this, with segmentation fault 11:

> Tom 50 60 70.5
>   Jerry 80.3 65 91
>   Mark 75.2 77 92.7
>   Segmentation fault: 11

Here is my program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct StudentList {
    string name;
    double scores[2];
};

int main() {

    ifstream marks;
    marks.open("table.txt");

    StudentList Student[50];

    int index = 0;

    string text;
    if (marks.fail()) {
        cout << "fail open" << endl;
    }

    while (marks >> text) {
        cout << text << " ";
        Student[index].name = text;
        marks >> Student[index].scores[0];
        cout << Student[index].scores[0] << " ";

        marks >> Student[index].scores[1];
        cout << Student[index].scores[1] << " ";

        marks >> Student[index].scores[2];
        cout << Student[index].scores[2] << " ";

        cout << endl;
        index++;
        cout << index << endl;
    }

    marks.close();

    return 0;
}
```

What exactly is the problem?

Comment: You have only allocated space for 2 scores: `double scores[2];` but try to read 3: `marks >> Student[index].scores[2];` Accessing the array out of bounds is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C, as in most modern programming languages, array indexing starts at 0, and the number in the deceleration is the size, not the last index. So

```
double scores[2];
```

declares an array of size 2, with indexes 0 and 1.

Comment: @Michelle The usual way to thank is to upvote/accept